# Getting new data in DOM without refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

I have page where I add time range, on button INSERT & SAVE send data to API and from response set data to table. But problem is, my data is not showing dynamically. I need refresh page to see changes. I try to use `$watch`, but this not working or I doing something wrong. Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jQQDMxml5sUmiKPLxA9N?p=preview).

Answer (score 3):

You made some mistakes:

1. `<div ng-controller="TimepickerDemoCtrl">` not wrapped whole stuff
2. `ng-submit` was changed to `ng-click`
3. as `urbanTimeRange` is array you should use `$watchCollection`
   instead of `$watch`

look at corrected [variant](http://plnkr.co/edit/s5vhJqu9rBFtPo9JTC0k?p=preview).

Comment: thnx, but this is my mistake because i take working bootstrap plnkr and add my code, in my code this working correct, but i have problem with $watch. On INSERT button i  send data to server, and on response DOM is not updated, i need to refresh view, and after refresh new data is here. I want instant update DOM

Comment: Where are you add new elements into `urbanTimeRange`? As you not change it `$watch` is not fired

Comment: after click on INSERT button send data to server, and with factory i call this link and set data $scope.urbanTimeRange = $scope.urbanConfig.screen_intervals;

Comment: This code not exists at your plunk, also you should use `$watchCollection` instead of `$watch`.

Comment: now exist... sry... i don't know that this is important

Answer (score 0):

thnx to @Slava Utesinov for starting point. Here is how I make this. 
First, for adding new time interval, I use this in `$http` success. First I push new data to `$scope` and after I `$watch` this `$scope` for change

```
 $scope.urbanTimeRange.push(data);
 $scope.$watchCollection('urbanTimeRange', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
}, true);
```

Also, when I remove time intervals, I use `splice` method and after `$watch` for change. Here we see `index`, I get `index` from my html where I track selected item in ng-repeat with `$index`.

This is controller:

```
$scope.urbanTimeRange.splice(index, 1);
$scope.$watchCollection('urbanTimeRange', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {
});
```

This is html

```
<tr ng-repeat='timeRange in urbanTimeRange track by $index'>
                            <td>{{timeRange.from_time | date:'shortTime'}}</td>
                            <td>{{timeRange.to_time | date:'shortTime'}}</td>
                            <td><angular-smartconfirm confirm="removeRow(timeRange.id, $index)"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></angular-smartconfirm></td>
                        </tr>
```